# Calling java from php

Tags: java, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call Java method from PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549745/call-java-method-from-php5)

How can I call a java application from a php application, taking note that they reside on the same server?

No WebServices or any http stuff.

Can I do that and how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to call a library or just execute a single line??

Comment: Looks like [this post][1] addresses your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website

Answer (score 5):

You can use php's [`exec(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to call java on the command line.

Comment: @Catalin Marin Which could potentially be a huge security risk for a web app. Be sure that your code uses a static, unchangeable string to call your Java code if you follow this path. You will have to ask yourself "What commands could a web user execute?". Especially if you are running your web server as root on a *nix system or an administrator on Windows.

Comment: @bakoyaro: Anyone running their web server as root (except in some very narrow, special circumstances, mainly in the embedded world) needs to immediately visit careers.SE and hire a competent sysadmin.

Comment: I strongly doubt this is what the original poster had in mind.